# RV hookup guy, for short? (3)

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

### RV hookup guy, for short? (3)

This is a clue that follows standard cryptic crossword rules. (That is, the clue contains a definition, another indicator as to the answer, and nothing else: [here](http://solving-cryptics.com)'s a link with more information about cryptics.) What's the solution?

Comment: this is a rebus not wordplay

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be:

> STU

because

> Stu hook's up (connects RstuV) and is a man's name - short for Stuart

Comment: Darn you and your lightning fast typing!

Comment: I was eating fish and chips and typing :)

Answer (score 12):

The answer could be

> WES

The three connections on an RV hookup are

> water, electricity & sewage (WES)

and

> Wes is is the short form of Wesley, a guy's name.

Comment: Not quite, but you're on the right track - note the [wordplay] tag.

Comment: This seems just as likely as the other answer - I don't see any reason why it's not valid, other than it not being the intended answer.

Comment: @question_asker  It's the rules of a cryptic.  The other answer is unambiguously correct for both definitions, and doesn't require obscure knowledge.  Also, the ? at the end indicates wordplay, the double meaning of "Hookup". As a starting point, never take anything at it's surface meaning.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore This one involves wordplay just as much as the other - and the "double meaning" of 'hookup' is arbitrarily important, without knowing the answer.

Comment: I'll argue it in chat if you want

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Nah, there's nothing to really argue. This answer meets the definition as much as the other - the only difference being that it's not arbitrarily silly enough.

Comment: I'm with @ChrisCudmore on this. It's very clever and deserves an upvote, but the letters in WES are arbitrarily assigned an order to make it work, whereas STU is unambiguously correct for the R-V link.

Comment: I'm waffling.  My objection to WES is that it require specialized knowledge, not that is not a possible answer.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore and ff - my point is ultimately that people who favor one particular answer are straining credulity claiming that one is """unambiguously""" correct in a way they wouldn't bother with on other questions with multiple answers.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that Tom and Chris Cudmore's answer is a *better* answer but this answer is valid too. In a cryptic crossword, the answer needs to fit the clue and *also* needs to fit in with the solutions to other clues (which resolves the ambiguity). In this case there are no other clues, so the ambiguity leaves open the possibility of multiple "correct" answers (incidentally, I don't think that cryptic crossword clues are a very good fit for this site for precisely that reason, but that's a separate topic...)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Hm, good point - if I post more cryptic clues I'll make sure to have them connected somehow to stop any potential ambiguities.

Answer (score 9):

> STU

Because

> abcdefghijklmnopqrSTUvwxyz, Stu is short for Stuart.

Comment: Note to OP - @tom gets it by mere seconds.